# Правильно ли говорить "тенденции оказывают влияние на..."?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли говорить "тенденции оказывают влияние на..."? Или тенденции не могут оказывать влияние?

Comment: Даже прогнозы оказывают влияние на... Приведите проблемную фразу целиком, чтобы оценить её правильность.

Comment: Эта тенденция оказывает непосредственное влияние на работу майнеров.

Answer (score 1):

Если предположить, что в предшествующих фразах обозначена суть реальных процессов, говорящих об определённой тенденции, то специалист, да и просто читатель, обязательно воспримет их в целом — как важные для оптимизации работы сведения. Но и тогда это будет лишь опосредованным фактором «влияния  на работу»: сама тенденция как некий сформулированный статистический материал не определяет последствий его публикации.

Может быть так?

*Выявление этой тенденции будет иметь определяющее значение в работе майнеров.*